# Cannot connect to SQL Server database - Cucumber, mssql nodejs, typescript

Tags: sql-server, cucumberjs

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database but I got an error and it says nothing to me...

This is my Db connection file:

```
import { error } from 'console'
import sql from 'mssql'

const sqlConfig = {
    user: process.env.USERNAME,
    password: process.env.PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DBNAME,
    server: process.env.SERVER,
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true, // for azure
        trustServerCertificate: false // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
    }
}

export class DbConnection {

    static async queryToDb(query: string) {
        try {
            // make sure that any items are correctly URL encoded in the connection string
            //console.log('Executing query: ' + query)
            await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
            const result = await sql.query(query)
            console.dir(result)
        } catch (err) {
            throw Error()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I got when I run tests:

> Error: a BeforeAll hook errored, process exiting: src\hooks\hooks.ts:22:
>
> at Runtime.runTestRunHooks (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\run_test_run_hooks.ts:32:19)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at Runtime.start (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\runtime\index.ts:103:5)
> at runCucumber (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\api\run_cucumber.ts:125:19)
> at Cli.run (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\cli\index.ts:82:25)
> at Object.run [as default] (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\node_modules@cucumber\cucumber\src\cli\run.ts:38:14)
> caused by: Error:
> at Function. (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\src\helper\db\db-connection.ts:43:23)
> at Generator.throw ()
> at rejected (C:\dev\allocator-frontend-e2e-tests\src\helper\db\db-connection.ts:6:65)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

What can be wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: The `queryToDb(query: string)` method is fundamentally flawed in the first place, because it will force you to build queries in a way that is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection. You should do some research on parameterized queries before going any further.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
try {
  ...
} catch (err) {
    throw Error()
}
```

you are throwing away any information of the caught error, without even looking at it. Details about the error are contained in the `err` which you can then inspect inside the catch block to find out more about the error.

You are just catching an error thrown in the try block, and with `throw Error()` you are creating a complete new error, which doesn't contain any information about the actual error. But as your testframework only receives that new error, it of course cannot tell you anything about the actual error.

Do

```
try {
  ...
} catch (err) {
  //optionally you can do some logging or whatever else
  //with the error you just caught

  //rethrow the same error, so the information will be passed on
  throw err;
}
```

instead, to pass on the information about the caught error to the outer level of exception handling. With this, also your testframework will be able to pick up and report information about the error.

Alternatively, remove the try/catch completely and do your error handling at a higher level in the code.